# Get value of input box, without a form?

Tags: php, forms, mysql

Does anyone know how I can get the value of an input box, without having a form? I want a submit button, but instead of submitting a form, I want it to change data in a MySQL database. Something like this maybe?

```
$img1="WHAT DO I PUT HERE?"
$idx=1  
$sql="INSERT INTO games SET img1='$img1' WHERE id=$idx";  
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Could I use that code on a "onclick" event? The input box's name and id is "img1".

Comment: imput is input? 
If so, then there is no way for PHP to know what it's value if <input is not in <form that you are sending...

Comment: Why would you care whether you use a form or not?  If you want a button and you want fields, that seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Where is the difference in using a input with a button and a form with an input with a button? You can do whatever you want with the form data, no one knows what you are doing at your server side.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the data from the input box to be submitted. The input boxes are not inside the form, so how would I get the data submitted?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to submit a form, the only two other ways of accomplishing this are to click a link with the data as query parameters in the url, or use AJAX to send the data to the server in the background.

update:

Javascript, as usual. You'd put a link or button somewhere on the page with "Send to Server" or whatever for the text. The script would pull your information from the input fields, and then send it on to the server via an AJAX call. Something along these lines (note that I'm using [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) for all this, as it makes life much easier than having to do the remote calls yourself):

```
 function clickHandler() {
     var img1 = $$("input[name='img1']")[0].value;

     var r = new Request.JSON({
         'url: 'http://yourserver.example.com/script.php',
         'method': 'post',
         'onComplete': function(success) { alert('AJAX call status: ' + (success ? 'succeeded': 'failed!'); },
         'onFailure': function() { alert('Could not contact server'); },
         'data': 'img1=' + img1
     }).send();
}
```

and on the server you'd have something like:

```
<?php

$img1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['img1']);
$idx=1;
$sql="INSERT INTO games SET img1='$img1' WHERE id=$idx";  
$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo (($result !== FALSE) ? 1 : 0);
```

You'd probably want something more complicated than this, but this is the basis of an AJAX application. Some client-side javascript that makes requests, and a script on the server that handles them and returns any data/errors as needed.

Comment: How would I get the data from the input boxes to be sent in the URL?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript, as it can access the living DOM, and hence any changes to it (like those in values of fields).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if your completely against using a form or just might not know how to keep it hidden.

You can create a hidden form that submits the info with the click of a button.

```
<form name="hidden-form" action="youraction.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitme" value="I get submitted">
<input type="hidden" name="submitmetoo" value="I get submitted">
<input type="hidden" name="submitmeaswell" value="I get submitted">
<input type="hidden" name="dontleavemeout" value="I get submitted">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

However anyone that looks at your html will be able to see this

Answer (score 0):

***I guess this is what you looking for.
this will only work if your html and php are on the same file...***

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<input type='text' id='user' placeholder='user'>
</body>
</html>


<?php
$val = "
<script>
document.write(document.querySelector('#user').value);
</script>
";
echo $val;
?>
```